# Android how to show the toolbar above keyboard

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-toolbar

I'm working on my app that I have created a toolbar to show at the bottom of the screen now I want to move the toolbar above keyboard whenever the keyboard is show. I have tried the following ways but it didn't work.

AndroidManifest:

```
 <activity
    android:name=".ComposeActivity"
    android:label="Compose"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyLogin.NoActionBar"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
 </activity>
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <include
        android:id="@+id/format_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/keyboard_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

keyboard_toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bold"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_format_bold_24" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/italic"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/bold"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_format_italic_24" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/underline"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/italic"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_format_underlined_24" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/color_text"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/underline"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_format_color_text_24" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/color_fill"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/color_text"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_format_color_fill_24" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/clear_formatting"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/color_fill"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_format_clear_24" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/close_format"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_close_24" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is what it show:

[image]

Here is what I want to achieve:

[image: enter code here]

Can you please show me an example how I can move the toolbar to the bottom of the screen just above the keyboard??